# Julia: Convert Dataframe with multiple string columns to float array

Tags: dataframe, julia

I have a DataFrame which has many String columns where they should be float64 instead. I would like to transform all the column at once and transform the dataframe into a float array. How can do this? Importantly, there are some float columns too.

```
df = DataFrame(a=["1", "2", "3"], b=["1.1", "2.2", "3.3"], c=[0.1, 0.2, 0.3])
# Verbose option
df.a = parse.(Float64, df.a)
df.b = parse.(Float64, df.b)
matrix = Matrix{Float64}(df)
# Is is possible to do this at once especially when there are float columns too?
# Here parse.(Float64, df.c) would throw an error
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way of doing this is by looping over the String columns:

```
for c ∈ names(df, String)
    df[!, c]= parse.(Float64, df[!, c])
end
```

Note that you don't need `Matrix{Float64}` if you've already turned everything into Floats, just `Matrix(df)` will do.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same question and landed on this page and found that the above code does not work for me, a slight change that made it work for me is:

```
for c ∈ names(df, Any)
    df[!, c]= Float64.(df[!, c])
end
```

Note that for the `names(df, Any)` argument Any can be specified as String or any other data type.